# How to create a certificate with hostname/domainname using keytool java

Tags: certificate, keytool

How to create a certificate with hostname/domainname (Example : www.exmaple.com) using keytool java?  When we configure SSL with this certificate, we should accept the request only with this name. (I mean not even with IP also it should not accept the requests).Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

When you press Enter, keytool prompts you to enter the server name, organizational unit, organization, locality, state, and country code.

You must type the **server name in response to keytool’s first promp**t, in which it asks for first and last names.

This will create a `keystore.jks` file containing a private key and your self signed certificate.

If you need to export the generated server certificate execute

```
keytool -export -alias selfsigned  -storepass changeit
-file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

See the full example [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying the **-ext** parameter:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias testCert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore testKeystore.p12 -validity 3650 -ext san=ip:127.0.0.1,dns:localhost
```